# Visual Studio Code (vscode) and Git

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I try to push code from Visual Studio Code interface, it requires me to enter my GitHub username and password. How can I save my GitHub credentials so it doesn't ask me to enter them every time I push my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a [Git credential helper](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/).

If you are using *Git for Windows* you can run the following command to save your credentials.

`git config --global credential.helper wincred`

For Mac/Linux see this [guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/11/18/git-credential-manager-for-mac-and-linux/) on how to make Git remember your credentials.

Otherwise, you can enable ssh access to your repo.